# Find highest possible x and y value of Points

Tags: sorting

I have measured points for fitting lines. The number of points I have measured in x-direction is the first value of the Point (e.g. X1) and the second value  of this point are the measured points in y-direction.

```
X1(2,9)
X2(9,3)
X3(5,4)
X4(6,4)
```

This means,that e.g. in X3 I have measured 5 points in x-direction and in y-direction I have measured 4 points. With the points in x-direction I will fit a line in x-direction and with the points in y-direction, I will fit a line in y-direction. To get better results, more points in x direction and y-direction are better then less. For example it is better to choose X4, then X1, because in X1 I have in y-direction 9-Points, but in x-direction only 2 points, which will give me a poor result in x-direction. In X4 I have both: a high number of points in x and in y-direction. So I can be sure, that the lines will be good enough. So I want to find this X#, where I have a (the) high(est) number of points in x and in y direction

Comment: Honestly, I don't get what kind of sort do you want...
What do you mean with `I want to sort this points by the higest possible x-value compared to the y-value.`?

Comment: I want to find out, which Point has the highest x-value and in combination the highest y-value

Comment: Your conditions are very unclear. How do you decide the combination? In P4, neither x nor y are the highest...

Comment: I want to have this point, where x AND y are the highest values as possible from all of the points given. For example, P2 has only the x value as a highest x-ccordinate of all points, y is not the highest y-coordinate of all points. So when you look at P4, then the x-value is the second higest value, but the y value is the highest value of all points.

Comment: Your requirements are still unclear. You say `when you look at P4 ... the y value is the highest value of all points` But it's not. `P1(2,9)` has the highest y value of all the points.... The relationship between `x`,`y` and the weighting of a point is unclear. Why is P4 'higher' than P2 or P1? Can you provide the expected sorting of these points?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your code? It seems like your X is on an ascending order and your Y is using the opposite order. Maybe like insert both x and y values on a variable then sort them with the same order as you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a function that ranks the 'fitness' of a point.

```
def fitness(point):
    '''
    ranks a point by the total number of points, 
    minus the difference between the number of x and y points.
    uses total number of points as a secondary rank
    '''
    num_points = sum(point)
    xydiff = max(point) - min(point)
    return num_points - xydiff, num_points
```

The above function should be adjusted, depending on how you want to want to weight the points.

```
>>> points = [(2,9), (9,3), (5,4), (6,4)]
>>> sorted(points, key=fitness, reverse=True)
[(6, 4), (5, 4), (9, 3), (2, 9)]
>>> max(points, key=fitness) # the most fit point
(6, 4)
```

Comment: I´m not sure, if I understand your algorithm. This is what I´m understanding: Example (6,4): num_points = (6+4); xydiff = 6-4 ...is this correct? But this is not working or I do not understand your code

Comment: @HanzDieter the docstring of the function explains the logic. In other words: the higher the total number of points, the higher ranked a point is. However, the greater the difference between number of x and y points, the rank is lowered. You can adjust the function to your needs.